# need help to display images in picturebox from resource only DLL in C# (winform)

Tags: c#, winforms, dll, compilation

I am a novice in visual studio and am creating winform that selects and displays a specific image in a picturebox, based on the users inputs through some sets of radio buttons.
The whole interface works well.

I tested it with around 50 pictures through the resx resources within the project itself and that also goes great.

Problem -> I will use around 3500 images (initially 3500, when project is complete it will be 10.000+ images) and whenever I add all these images into the resx, it just stops working.

Possible solutions:

1. Load the pictures from an external file structure (can do and is easy, but I want to be able to compile it so that the endusers cannot see,download or modify the 'images' - the images should only be 'viewable' through the app) .
   If there is a way to include the folder structure (hidden/coded within the exe) than that would be my preferred choice, but I seem unable to find that. (I can then afterwards obfuscate the exe and have 'some' protection)
   it is a very easy 'folder structure' (4 folders each containing between 1000 and 3500 images in the end when all modules are finished)
2. Using a DLL resources only archive and include it in the build.
   I am testing around with this (with low amount of images firstly to get it to work), but I run into some problems.
   I made a DLL only containing some resx resources (set of png images)- first time I do this, not sure if I should add or change some settings there??? (I made the resources 'public')
   I referenced to this DLL in my main application's form. I also did the 'using ...' on top.
   I am able to see the resources when I try to load them into the picturebox.
   The program throws out an error that it cannot convert 'byte' to 'image'.
   I was following the advise from a very old thread here, where it shows that theway to reference directly to the DLL public resources should work... but it doesn't.

Any advice on either to use system 1 or 2 and possible help or solutions for them?
Or any better idea I have overlooked or am unaware of?
(pictures are 277kb each and it is important that users have no direct access to them to copy/past/distribute/...).
I prefer to have the image resources 'in the build' if possible and also not a 'cloud like solution as I want everything to be accessible in 'no internet scenario's' such as being in a plane, etc.

[lib reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJOQ4.png)

[lib activated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPiDB.png)

[old thread related to this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4ZV1.png)

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyssN.png)

[Picbox command + error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3YBt.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say that you added images to the .resx, I'm not sure how you went about doing that. But one thing I would try is to embed them by manipulating the .csproj file directly. I tried generating 3500 alternating test images (you said 277kb these happen to be 244kb).

[image: solution explorer window]

Next, I generated tags I could copy into the .csproj

```
// Copy to cs.proj file
for (int i = 0; i <= 3500; i++) 
{
    Debug.WriteLine(@$"    <EmbeddedResource Include=""Images\sample-image-{i.ToString("D5")}.png"" />");
}
```

with the final result in .csproj being:

```
  <ItemGroup>
      <EmbeddedResource Include="Images\sample-image-00000.png" />
      <EmbeddedResource Include="Images\sample-image-00001.png" />
      <EmbeddedResource Include="Images\sample-image-00002.png" />
      <EmbeddedResource Include="Images\sample-image-00003.png" />
      <EmbeddedResource Include="Images\sample-image-00004.png" />
      <EmbeddedResource Include="Images\sample-image-00005.png" />
      <EmbeddedResource Include="Images\sample-image-00006.png" />
      <EmbeddedResource Include="Images\sample-image-00007.png" />
      <EmbeddedResource Include="Images\sample-image-00008.png" />
      <EmbeddedResource Include="Images\sample-image-00009.png" />
      <EmbeddedResource Include="Images\sample-image-00010.png" />
      <EmbeddedResource Include="Images\sample-image-00011.png" />
      .
      .
      .
      <EmbeddedResource Include="Images\sample-image-03497.png" />
      <EmbeddedResource Include="Images\sample-image-03498.png" />
      <EmbeddedResource Include="Images\sample-image-03499.png" />
      <EmbeddedResource Include="Images\sample-image-03500.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

---

Then all you need is an extension to load an embedded image into the picture box.

```
static class Extensions
{
    public static Image FromNamedResource(this string name)
    {
        using (Stream imageStream = typeof(MainForm).Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(name))
        {
            if (imageStream == null)
            {
                return new Bitmap(0, 0);
            }
            else
            {
                return new Bitmap(imageStream);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The executable is a whopping 3/4 of a gigabyte, but it seems to build and run ok. Perhaps you can use this as a starting point and experiment further.

---

Here's the code I used to test this answer:

[image: images 1 and 2 of 3500]

```
namespace images_from_embedded_resource
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        const int MAX_IMAGES = 3500;
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            buttonUpArrow.Text = "\u2191";
            buttonDownArrow.Click += (sender, e) => Index = Math.Min(Index + 1, MAX_IMAGES);
            buttonDownArrow.Text = "\u2193";
            buttonUpArrow.Click += (sender, e) => Index = Math.Max(Index - 1, 0);
            pictureBox.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
            Index = 0;

#if GENERATE_TEST_IMAGES
            for (int i = 2; i <= 3500; i++) 
            {
                // Alternating test images
                if(i%2 == 0)
                {
                    File.Copy(
                        @"D:\Github\stackoverflow\Tozz\images-from-embedded-resource\images-from-embedded-resource\Images\sample-image-00000.png",
                       $@"D:\Github\stackoverflow\Tozz\images-from-embedded-resource\images-from-embedded-resource\Images\sample-image-{i.ToString("D5")}.png",
                       overwrite: true
                    );
                }
                else
                {
                    File.Copy(
                        @"D:\Github\stackoverflow\Tozz\images-from-embedded-resource\images-from-embedded-resource\Images\sample-image-00001.png",
                       $@"D:\Github\stackoverflow\Tozz\images-from-embedded-resource\images-from-embedded-resource\Images\sample-image-{i.ToString("D5")}.png",
                       overwrite: true
                    );
                }
            }
#endif
#if GENERATE_CSPROJ_TAGS
            // Copy to cs.proj file
            for (int i = 0; i <= 3500; i++) 
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(@$"    <EmbeddedResource Include=""Images\sample-image-{i.ToString("D5")}.png"" />");
            }
#endif
            // Make sure resources are embedded
            foreach (var name in typeof(MainForm).Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames().Where(_ => _.Contains(".png")))
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(name);
            }
        }
        int _index = -1;
        public int Index
        {
            get => _index;
            set
            {
                if (!Equals(_index, value))
                {
                    _index = value;
                    pictureBox.BackgroundImage = $"images_from_embedded_resource.Images.sample-image-{Index.ToString("D5")}.png".FromNamedResource();
                    Text = $"{Index.ToString("D5")}";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [Clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/images-from-embedded-resource.git) this sample .

Comment: Thanks a lot.
It for sure gives me another and new insight in what to try.
I will test it easily first in a clone of my solution with a 'mini manually embedded folder' and when I get everything working right (including the extension) I will try and add the full images folder and cross my fingers.

In the future I would need more or less 2 folders of 3500 images and 2 folders of 1200 images.
Would you advise (if I get it to work) to still try and embed them all directly in this way (using 4 folders), or do it differently ?

Many thanks already for the input!!!

Comment: I think you were on the right track with building multiple, smaller dlls containing a subset of the images. The extension method that I showed for `FromNamedResource` will work fine with those other assemblies but instead of `typeof(MainForm).Assembly` you will use a type defined in that other assembly to retrieve the embedded resources they hold.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
I will test it 'phased' to solve 1 part of my little puzzle at a time and progress to the final solution.
And yeah, "subset DLL's" make most sense in my usecase as in the 'final' project I will have 4 disctinct different 'chapters' that can then easily be updated 1 at a time (when needed) in a hassle free way (image names and amount of images wil lalways remain the same, only the image on it's own can be updated afterwards - so an easy DLL swap should do the trick in the future)

Comment: Will do and I'll keep you posted here over the next few days :)

Comment: I managed to add the extension and to get the images to load in the first test case.
In this test case I just embedded a few png in the main application.
Next phase, make a small DLL to test how it works then.
Do I add the extension in the DLL file (as it will load it anyway as I reference to it) ?